# Building application - configure of angularjs+bootstrap3 with database

Tags: angularjs, logging, webpack

I am creating my first, simple site but dont know what tools pick for this.

I want angularjs+bootstrap3 and for logging PHP+MySQL.

So:

-webpack is good, but not for connecting with other databases?

-npm is good too, but when I run project - angular cant load.

How can I connect this all?

Comment: Think of it as 2 different apps. A front end angular app and a back end api app

Comment: So it is correct to using webpack for bootstrap and angularjs? When i finish, then i need to care about backend side?

Comment: Sure you can do that

Comment: Okey so in theory for now, i finished full front end side - what to do then? What to search about? Can I include php with mysql or every backend language i want?

Comment: depends what server it is all run on and what is available on that server. If it is a node server can all be one app

Comment: I've got information, that server which i want is good for php and mysql so i prefer that. When I finish my front end app, I will search more about backend. but thank you, I thought that my webpack code is useless

Comment: Ok. So write some php to do the data handling and use webpack to create angular build files and upload those. A php framework will help get the data handling set up a lot easier